# Adjust window height on click

Tags: jquery, onclick, window-resize

I have a div #more with width 100% and height auto that wraps my content.

I want that div to resize to adjust window height on a link click.

My script **almost** works, I click on the link, i see the scrollbar getting smaller (proof that the window has resized BUT the div resizes only **after** the first scroll action...why is that ? :(

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#target" ).click(function(){
  function resizeSection(tag) {
    var docHeight = $(window).height();  // Get the height of the browser window
    var docWidth = $(window).width();    // Get the width of the browser window
    $(tag).css({'height': docHeight + 'px', 'width': docWidth + 'px', 'display': 'block'});
  }
  $('#more').each(function(){  
    resizeSection(this);  // Call the function and make sure to pass 'this'
  });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('#more').each(function(){
      resizeSection(this);
    });
  });
});
});
```

And this is the trigger : `<div id="target">click</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good way of making this happen, and the container resizes to fit window height very smooth and likable.

```
$('.more').click(function(){
    var isFullscreen = false;
    var d = {};
    var speed = 900; 
    if(!isFullscreen){ // MAXIMIZATION - maximize the container to fit window
        d.height = $(window).height();; 
        isFullscreen = true;
    }
    else{ // MINIMIZATION - minimize the container to a predifined size   
        d.height = 500px;            
        isFullscreen = false;
    }

    $(this).animate(d,speed)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

in first : put your more div in the beginning of the body.
if i understanding you clear, you don't need each function on one element.  try this. it's work fine, if that what you want

```
$( "#click" ).click(function() {
    //with outerHeight and width you get size including margin and padding       
    var docHeight = $(document).outerHeight(true);  // Get the height of the document window
    var docWidth = $(document).outerWidth(true);    // Get the width of the document window

    $('#more').css({

      "width": docWidth + "px",
      "height": docHeight + "px",
      "position": "absolute",//if this div is main container you don't need this 
      "top" :0,//and this 
      "left": 0,//and this
      "z-index": 1111//and this


    });

});
```